# Kendo UI (Multi Select Dropdown) - Change data values from External file

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-multiselect

I am using Kendo UI (Multi Select Dropdown) and I want to change the option values of it from external script file.

This is working as expected **[{Online DEMO}](http://dojo.telerik.com/AkEke)** only if I am not initializing the Kendo feature in html page.

So, I have already options in html page:

**My HTML Page:**

```
    <select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple" class="mySelectBox">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="multiselect2" multiple="multiple">
      <option>Option 3</option>
      <option>Option 4</option>
    </select>

    <script language="Javascript">
      $("#multiselect, multiselect2").kendoMultiSelect();
    </script>
```

and trying to replace the values from `external.js` file as:

```
     var dataMultiselect = ["New Value 1", "New Value 2", "New Value 3"];
      $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
        dataSource: dataMultiselect
      });
      $("#multiselect2").kendoMultiSelect({
        dataSource: dataMultiselect
      });
```

**It is not working... Any Help can save my day**

Getting Error as "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change data values with function *setDataSource*

```
var data2 = ["Five", "Six"];
var multiselect = $("#multiselect").data("kendoMultiSelect");
multiselect.setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: data2 }));
```

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/AkEke/2)

Comment: Hi **@Ademar**... almost there... but I am getting new values as 'undefined'... if it is same file, its working correctly

Comment: ... **May be because of first data values are coming from another file (html file)?**

Comment: Hm, so thats strange, On my computer it works also with external js file. Try yet add dataTextField and dataValueField properties into multiselect http://dojo.telerik.com/AkEke/4 ... but I am not giving much chances that it will change something... I will try think what can cause problem yet, but right now I have no idea..

Comment: Sorry again... no change as you said... One more thing is: I do not have control on changing the htmls...

from HTML page:
`<select id="recipientSelect" multiple="multiple" accesskey="w" data-placeholder="-- Select --" class="required">
      <option>Option 1 (Test)</option>
<option>Option 2 (Tes2t)</option>
</select>`

**And the script is:**
       `jQuery("#recipientSelect").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataSource: data,
  filter: "contains"
 });`

Anything wrong with the above code?

Comment: And also in your latest example, default values are showing as "undefined" :(

Comment: it looks correct ( http://dojo.telerik.com/AkEke/6 as you can see). I will try search yet and reproduce the problem. Is displaying any error browser's console or something (better chrome console than IE, i have figured out, that chrome console shows more)

Comment: Hi **@Ademar**.. it is working as expected... but getting the 2 dropdowns with old values and new values... If I select "One" and "Two", not getting any error... If select other any value from default dropdown, I am getting the error as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined"